# How can I get right data from httpd_req_recv() method

Tags: apache, esp32

I used esp-idf to develop a esp32 app,I need to receive data from other devices via wifi.
Here is the esp-idf code

```
static esp_err_t handler_get_data(httpd_req_t *req){
ESP_LOGI(TAG,"handler_get_data called");
char request[req->content_len];
int ret = httpd_req_recv(req, request, req->content_len);
printf("%s\n", request);
if(ret <= 0){
    if(ret == HTTPD_SOCK_ERR_TIMEOUT){
        ESP_LOGW(TAG,"socket timeout");
        httpd_resp_send_408(req);
    }
    ESP_LOGE(TAG,"httpd_req_recv failed");
    return ESP_FAIL;
}
char* data = "200";
return httpd_resp_send(req, data, strlen(data));
```

}

And I posted data from python by code below:

```
requests.post("http://192.168.4.1/post", data="test")
```

However, in console，I got charrctor like this:

I (5354943) app_httpd: handler_get_data called

@���?��?l�

I (5362453) app_httpd: handler_get_data called

@���?��?l�

I (5367483) app_httpd: handler_get_data called

@���?0�?l�

I have tried to use ways like text.decode("utf-8") and data = {"data":data} ,Any case ,I'll get strange chars , whats's wrong with the code,I just cant solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I got it,it is for printf function,
to print a right string,length is essential.

```
printf("%.*s\n", ret, request);
```